# A bijection between ordered lambda terms and rooted planar maps?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, pl.programming-languages, lambda-calculus, planar-graphs

Consider the following recurrence in two parameters $n$ and $k$:

\begin{aligned}
NF(0,k) &= 0 \\
NF(n,k) &= Neu(n,k) + NF(n-1,k+1) \\
Neu(n,k) &= [n=1 \wedge k=1] + \sum_{l=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^k Neu(l,i) \cdot NF(n-l,k-i)
\end{aligned}
The expression $NF(n,k)$ counts the number of (untyped) **ordered** *lambda terms in normal form* of length $n$ with $k$ free variables. Recall that lambda terms are either variables, lambda abstractions or applications
\begin{aligned}
t &::= x \mid \lambda x.t \mid t\ u
\end{aligned}
that a term is **ordered** if every free or bound variable occurs exactly once **and in the order it was introduced**, and that a term is *normal* if it contains no subterms of the form $(\lambda x.t)\ u$. I take the length of a lambda term to be defined by
\begin{aligned}
|x| &= 1 \\
|\lambda x.t| &= 1 + |t| \\
|t\ u| &= |t| + |u|
\end{aligned}
The recurrence for $NF(n,k)$ is derived from a standard inductive characterization of normal lambda terms (in a mutual induction with "neutral" terms -- for background see [these notes](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/99-atp/handouts/intercal.pdf), or slide 9 of [this talk](http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/talkMcGill2012Normalization.pdf)).

$NF(n,0)$ thus counts the number of *closed* normal **ordered** lambda terms of length $n$.

I computed $NF(n,0)$ for $n=0..14$, and derived this sequence:
$$
0,0,1,0,2,0,9,0,54,0,378,0,2916,0,24057
$$
Now, dropping all of the 0s and plugging the result into the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/), I landed on [A000168](https://oeis.org/A000168), whose first few terms are
$$
1, 2, 9, 54, 378, 2916, 24057, 208494
$$
and which user Don Knuth says corresponds to the
$$\text{Number of rooted planar maps with }n\text{ edges.}$$
A nice explanation (with illustrative pictures) of planar maps is given in [these slides](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~schaeffe/Biblio/Slides/Tatihou.pdf) (and also [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0304034v2.pdf)); in particular, a *planar map* is defined as a proper embedding of a connected graph in the plane (considered up to homeomorphisms of the plane), and it is *rooted* if one root edge is marked on the infinite face and oriented in counterclockwise direction.

**Conjecture**: for all $n$, we have
\begin{aligned}
NF(2n,0) &= \#\text{ of rooted planar maps with }n\text{ edges} \\
NF(2n+1,0) &= 0
\end{aligned}

Questions: Is the conjecture true? Can you prove it by exhibiting a simple bijection between **ordered** lambda terms and rooted planar maps?

---

**Update** (12 May 2014): I realized that the way I originally explained the conjecture was not strictly speaking correct, since the recurrence for $NF$ actually counts lambda terms which are **ordered** and not merely linear.  (For example, both $\lambda x.\lambda y.x\ y$ and $\lambda x.\lambda y.y\ x$ are linear lambda terms in normal form, but only $\lambda x.\lambda y.x\ y$ is ordered.  Up to normalization, the two ordered linear lambda terms of length 4 are $\lambda x.\lambda y.x\ y$ and $\lambda x.x\ (\lambda y.y)$.) I am still looking for a proof of this conjecture.

Comment: Thanks, I shouldn't have conflated them. I corrected that, and added a definition for "rooted planar map" (together with a pair of links).

Comment: I think the answer is likely to be "yes" to both of your questions. The combinatorics of linear (and affine) lambda-terms was recently studied in depth by Olivier Bodini, Danièle Gardy and Alice Jacquot in _Asymptotics and random sampling for BCI and BCK lambda terms_, Theor. Comput. Sci. 502:227-238, 2013 (I can't find a free online version, sorry).  They study the generating series and also show a bijective correspondence with certain kinds of combinatorial maps similar to the ones you mention. However, their analysis applies to **all** linear $\lambda$-terms, not just the normal forms...

Comment: @DamianoMazza Thanks! I found a free version of the paper at http://dmg.tuwien.ac.at/dgardy/Papers/LogiqueQuantitative/BCI.pdf, and will have a look.

Comment: Good! Anyway, for those who read french (Noam, I'm pretty sure you do), Alice's thesis is freely available [here](http://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/~jacquot/thesejacquot.pdf). The study of linear and affine $\lambda$-terms constitutes Part III of her thesis and may be even more detailed than in the paper.